# c# check if a string has a certain word

Tags: c#, string, vmware, cosmos

I am using Cosmos to make a simple OS to understand a bit about it.
If I want to make a command line called echo that echos user's input, first I need to check if the input has "echo" in front of it.
For example, if i input "echo hello world", I want my VMware to echo "hello world" because echo is my new command line.

What I tried is

```
String input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input.Contains("echo")) {
    Console.WriteLine(input} 
}
```

It's not efficient. First, VMware says

```
IndexOf(..., StringComparison) not fully supported yet!
```

And the user might type "echo" in the middle of his string, not as the command.

Are there any efficient ways to solve this?

Comment: Can you use StartsWith?

Comment: If you cannot use `IndexOf` I'm pretty sure you're out of luck unless you just check the actual characters `if(input[0] == 'e' && input[1] == 'c' ....)`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && input.StartsWith("echo"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

You should use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`. Better to check first whether a string is null or empty.

Comment: with this code in my protected override void Run(), VMware quits automatically as soon as I input anything without looping. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can split it using space, and check with the switch.

```
String input = Console.ReadLine();
String[] input_splited = input.split(' ');
switch(input_splited[0]){
    case 'echo':
      String value = input_splited[1];
      Console.WriteLine(value);
      break;
    case 'other_cmd':
      String other_value = input_splited[1];
      break;
}
```

I hope it works for u. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that you need something like that:

```
       const string command = "echo";
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input.IndexOf(command) != -1)
        {                
            var index = input.IndexOf("echo");               
            var newInputInit = input.Substring(0, index);
            var newInputEnd = input.Substring(index + command.Length);
            var newInput = newInputInit + newInputEnd;
            Console.WriteLine(newInput);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```